# .NET Regex: how to retrieve multiple matches on multiple lines

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following Regex:

```
\b((.|\n)*)=((.|\n)*)new((.|\n)*)\(\)
```

It is used to detect an object assignment from a c# source code string,

like this one: `var a = new Person();`

it works fine when I have only one match, but if I try to process this:

```
var a = new Person();
var x = new WebClient();
```

It returns only one match, like this: `{var a = new Person(); var x = new WebClient()}`

I need to extract both matches. How do I do that , I'm relatively new to regex and I have no idea what to do.

When I test my regex on RegExr , it works just fine (with the global checkbox checked)..

Comment: Just out of interest does it matter if you match commented out code, assignments that include casts and the like. What about new arrays? /* var a = new Person(); */ var b = (new Man() as Person);

Comment: well, yes it does, but I'm just getting started, guess I will have to figure that out

Comment: You are in that case going to reach a dead end using Regular Expressions alone. Try looking into what a Parser does. Regular expressions are only really useful for tokenizing a language like C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression should get you started. Try passing in the Multiline regex option rather than trying to deal with newlines in the regex itself:

```
var src = @"var a = new Person();
var x = new WebClient();";
var pattern = @"(\w+\s*)(\w*\s*)=\s+new\s+(\w+)\(\)";
var expr = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach(Match match in expr.Matches(src) )
{
    var assignType = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var id = match.Groups[2].Value;
    var objType = match.Groups[3].Value;        
}
```

That said, there are (much) better tools than RegEx to deal with C# parsing, are you interested in those?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed , thank you.

Yes, what tools can you recommend, I already installed Express..

Comment: NRefactory includes a C# parser, and the Roslyn Project may be of help.
https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Comment: Roslyn is cool, but the problem is that I'm developing for android, using mono.

Comment: Then NRefactory is exactly what you want, I think, it is Mono-friendly (in fact uses Mono.Cecil internally)

Comment: Sounds awesome, I will check it out. Tyvm

Answer (score 1):

\n is allowing it to match new line.

This works for me against your test data in expresso:

```
\b((.)*)=((.)*)new((.)*)\(\)
```

If you don't need the matching groups - the brackets - this seems to work as well:

```
\b.*=.*new.*\(\)
```

This is possibly a better fit than using . (any character).

```
\b[\w\s]*=[\w\s]*new[\w\s]*\(\)
```

If you're confident the code base has exact spacing (e.g. enforced by something like StyleCop) then you can get more specific again with regards to the \w (word character) and \s (space character).

Also I'm not sure if it is intentional, but you're not matching the ; at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named groups. I modified the pattern to the following and the groups named `asgn` will match a whole assignment:

```
(?<asgn>\b\w+\s+\w+\s*\=\s*new\s+\w+\([^)]*\)\s*;)
```

This is how to access the named group:

```
string pat = @"(?<asgn>\b\w+\s+\w+\s*\=\s*new\s+\w+\([^)]*\)\s*;)";
string input = @"var a = new Person();
                var x = new WebClient();";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pat))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["asgn"].Value);
}
```

If you need to parse and extract each part of the assignment, you can name more groups into the pattern, as the following:

```
(?<asgn>\b(?<vtype>\w+)\s+(?<name>\w+)\s*\=\s*new\s+(?<type>\w+)\((?<args>[^)]*)\)\s*;)
```

with which you can extract variable-type, variable name, type, and constructor args from the matched string.